# Error when trying to removeLine on item_fulfillment

Tags: netsuite, record, sublist

I am trying to transform a sales order to an Item fulfillment and remove some item lines but I get the following error:

> name : SSS_INVALID_SUBLIST_OPERATION
>
> message: You have attempted an invalid sublist or line item operation.
> You are either trying to access a field on a non-existent line
> or you are trying to add or remove lines from a static sublist

My code:

```
// Transform the record 
var objRecord = record.transform({
                    fromType: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
                    fromId: soid,
                    toType: record.Type.ITEM_FULFILLMENT,
                    isDynamic: true,
                });

// Remove second location 
var linecount = objRecord.getLineCount({sublistId: 'item'});
for (var i = 0; i < linecount; i++) {
   objRecord.selectLine({sublistId: "item",line: i});
   var locationid = objRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: 'item',fieldId: 'location'});
   if (locationid != 15)
      objRecord.removeLine({sublistId: 'item',line: i});
}
```

There are 10 lines in the Sales order. Only 1 has some quantity allocated and ready to be fulfilled, maybe when I try to delete it that causes the error? But it seems the errors come from something else.

I tried to set: `isDynamic: false` (same error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not due to the index of the lines but to the operation on the record. On an item fulfillment the function `objRecord.removeLine` is not available.
To remove rows from the fulfillment item it we have to use :

```
objRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
    sublistId: 'item',
    fieldId: 'itemreceive',
    value : false
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Start deleting from the bottom of the list.

The value of `linecount` changes after each successful delete. Eventually, `i` will get a value that doesn't exist anymore.